# Generate an Access Token for an already authenticated user in ASP.NET OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

Not sure if I am asking the right question here.. maybe I need a refresh token. But basically what I am after is a shove in the right direction for this issue..

I have implemented OWIN on an ASP.NET MVC web application. All the auth works great but I have an issue with spawning new windows that do not exist in the same 'session' as the original auth request. This would be ok in a browser situation but the new session in being opened in an application that does not support HTML, so the user cannot login again the new session.

The current setup is using the default cookie based OWIN middleware, so maybe this isn't the best option.

Basically the way I see this working is that I append the 'new window' url with a querystring that is something like `?access_token=hjo324rifnblah` and the server can re-authentication from that.

I am open to any other suggestions as well, however I am locked into using OWIN and it must launch this new application from a `<a href="" />` in a browser.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "the new session in being opened in an application that does not support HTML" ?

Comment: @LeftyX By that I mean I am using forms authentication. Because of this I cannot show the login form for that application. The best way to explain how it will work is similar to the Dropbox desktop application. When you click the 'Goto my dropbox' link it fetches a token from the Drop box website and appends it to the URL to your Dropbox folder. This skips the login process as the token authenticates for you.

Comment: Could you explain the layers involved? Is the 'new window' a asp.net application with forms authentication? can you change the code? are you talking about bearer tokens or simple cookie? Cheers.